# Shortest path with a fixed number of edges

Tags: algorithm, path, dijkstra

Find the shortest path through a graph in efficient time, with the additional constraint that the path must contain exactly *n* nodes.

We have a directed, weighted graph. It may, or may not contain a loop. We can easily find the shortest path using Dijkstra's algorithm, but Dijkstra's makes no guarantee about the number of edges.

The best we could come up with was to keep a list of the best n paths to a node, but this uses  a huge amount of memory over vanilla Dijkstra's.

Comment: This was an in-class example for Zhe Dang's Algorithms class, it was not assigned as homework. 

I just thought it was an interesting problem.

Comment: I don't think you can satisfy both "shortest path" and "a fixed number of edges" constraints.

Comment: It think it means that "of the paths that contain exactly n nodes, find the shortest". Note that there may not be an answer (e.g. all paths take more than n nodes).

Comment: Nick D - read the problem as "Given the paths that have n edges, which of these has the shortest path?"  It's certainly satisfiable - he's just wanting an efficient way to find it.

Comment: If "the path must contain exactly n nodes", then the "shortest path" will be exactly n nodes long.  The way this is worded, all you have to do is find ANY path consisting of n nodes.

Comment: mbeckish - it's a weighted graph, so I think he's asking for the "least expensive path" with exactly n nodes (er, edges).

Comment: This just builds up to ideas that lead to the Bellman-Ford algorithm to compute shortest paths in a graph with possibly negative edges (but no negative cycles)

Comment: Try a binary search over the number of edges in a minimal path, while adjusting the weights, such that a certain number of edges in a solution is enforced.

Answer (score 8):

It is a simple dynamic programming algorithm.

Let us assume that we want to go from vertex `x` to vertex `y`.

Make a table `D[.,.]`, where `D[v,k]` is the cost of the shortest path of length `k` from the starting vertex `x` to the vertex `v`.

```
Initially D[x,1] = 0. Set D[v,1] = infinity for all v != x.
For k=2 to n:
  D[v,k] = min_u D[u,k-1] + wt(u,v), where we assume that wt(u,v) is infinite for missing edges. 
  P[v,k] = the u that gave us the above minimum.
```

The length of the shortest path will then be stored in D[y,n].

If we have a graph with fewer edges (sparse graph), we can do this efficiently by only searching over the `u` that `v` is connected to. This can be done optimally with an array of adjacency lists.

To recover the shortest path:

```
Path = empty list
v = y
For k= n downto 1:
  Path.append(v)
  v = P[v,k]
Path.append(x)
Path.reverse()
```

The last node is `y`. The node before that is `P[y,n]`. We can keep following backwards, and we will eventually arrive at `P[v,2] = x` for some `v`.

Comment: could you please give full algorithm code. I don't think your current algorithm is working, although the idea is correct.

Comment: A path of length `k` is conventionally understood as the number of edges along the path. Thus, the table `D[v,k]` shall be the cost of the shortest path of length `k-1` from the starting node to the vertex `v`. Or, it is the shortest path containing `k` nodes from the starting node to the vertex `v`, if we stick to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative that comes to my mind is a depth first search (as opposed to Dijkstra's breadth first search), modified as follows:

- stop "depth"-ing if the required vertex count is exceeded
- record the shortest found (thus far) path having the correct number of nodes.

Run time may be abysmal, but it should come up with the correct result while using a very reasonable amount of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem.  Did you discuss using a heuristic graph search (such as A*), adding a penalty for going over or under the node count?  This may or may not be admissible, but if it did work, it may be more efficient than keeping a list of all the potential paths.

In fact, you may be able to use backtracking to limit the amount of memory being used for the Dijkstra variation you discussed.

Answer (score 0):

A rough idea of an algorithm:

Let A be the start node, and let S be a set of nodes (plus a path).  The invariant is that at the end of step n, S will all nodes that are exactly n steps from A and the paths will be the shortest paths of that length. When n is 0, that set is {A (empty path)}.  Given such a set at step n - 1, you get to step n by starting with an empty set S1 and

```
for each (node X, path P) in S
  for each edge E from X to Y in S, 
    If Y is not in S1, add (Y, P + Y) to S1
    If (Y, P1) is in S1, set the path to the shorter of P1 and P + Y
```

There are only n steps, and each step should take less than max(N, E), which makes the 
  entire algorithm O(n^3) for a dense graph and O(n^2) for a sparse graph.

This algorith was taken from looking at Dijkstra's, although it is a different algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

let say we want shortest distance from node x to y of k step 
simple dp solution would be

A[k][x][y] = min over { A[1][i][k] + A[t-1][k][y] }
k varies from 0 to n-1

```
A[1][i][j] = r[i][j]; p[1][i][j]=j;
for(t=2; t<=n; t++)
for(i=0; i<n; i++) for(j=0; j<n; j++)
{
A[t][i][j]=BG; p[t][i][j]=-1;
for(k=0; k<n; k++) if(A[1][i][k]<BG && A[t-1][k][j]<BG)
if(A[1][i][k]+A[t-1][k][j] < A[t][i][j])
{
A[t][i][j] = A[1][i][k]+A[t-1][k][j];
p[t][i][j] = k;
}
}

trace back the path
void output(int a, int b, int t)
{
while(t)
{

cout<<a<<" ";
a = p[t][a][b];
t--;
}
cout<<b<<endl;
}
```