# boost c++ Astar with restrictions

Tags: c++, boost, graph, grammar, a-star

I am using the astar algorithm of boost http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/graph/doc/astar_search.html

I would like to integrate a length condition for the path length from start node to the goal node. More specifically I try to find a chain of digits with exact length of 11 digits. One idea could be the integration into the visitor pattern of the boost A*-implementation. But until now I found no good solution.

More general I am looking for a method to integrate a grammar check into the A*-algorithm. In my specific example the grammar could be expressed by a regular pattern like ^[1-9]\d{10}$ Each node represents a character (here a digit).
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Please show some example code you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

You probably won't be able to integrate it into A* easily, but your problem has already been discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1690347/shortest-path-with-a-fixed-number-of-edges)

EDIT: It seems there is already a [shortest path algorithm with resource constraints](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/graph/doc/r_c_shortest_paths.html) implemented in Boost, which is related to your problem, as *sehe* pointed out.

### Longer answer:

I believe it is not possible to directly use variants of Dijkstra's algorithm (including A*) to restrict the path length in general, since for every node you reach, you would need to keep track of a shortest path for *every* distinct path length (in terms of the number of edges) leading there.

What you are describing in your last paragraph is a simplified form of a *Language-constrained shortest path problem*, first investigated by [Barrett et al.](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0097539798337716)
The paper describes an algorithm that solves the general problem of shortest paths with constraints on the edge labels in polynomial time for regular expressions.
However, you need some knowledge on formal languages and regular automata to understand it.

The basic idea is to

- construct a non-deterministic automaton M(G) from your input graph G with special handling for the source s and target t
- construct a non-deterministic automaton M(R) for the regular language R describing the allowed paths and then
- construct the intersection between these two automata, which accepts exactly the paths from s to t which fulfill the constraints given by the regular language

On this automaton you can then run a normal shortest path algorithm to find several candidates of which you take the shortest one.

Comment: Relevant http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/graph/doc/r_c_shortest_paths.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. Both answers are a great help of solving my problem.

Comment: I found an alternative way of solving the problem. I added in the visitor the following code snippet:
    template <class Vertex>
class astar_goal_visitor : public boost::default_astar_visitor
{
public:
 astar_goal_visitor(Vertex goal) : m_goal(goal) {}
 template <class Graph>
 void examine_vertex(Vertex u, Graph& g) 
 {
  if (u == m_goal)
  {

   int cnt = 0;
   list<Vertex> shortest_path;
   for (Vertex v = m_goal;; v = (*preDecessorMap)[v]) 
   {
    shortest_path.push_front(v);
    cnt++;
    if ((*preDecessorMap)[v] == v)
     break;

   }

Comment: I found an alternative way of solving the problem (see last comment). I added in the visitor a pointer to the preDecessorMap. After reaching a  (possible) goal I check in the first step the length of the path by using the preDecessorMap. If this check is OK I throw      found_goal() otherwise I continue the search. It is not so elegant like the proposed methods, but it does the job.